# Transition superseed error when deleting data from db in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that is basically like a forum. Users can create threads and then comment inside. It all works but when a user deletes his comment, he gets redirected to homepage with this error.

```
Error: transition superseded
at $StateProvider.$get (https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.2/release/angular-ui-router.js:2909:37)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4842:19)
at http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4636:37
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4783:32)
at https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.2/release/angular-ui-router.js:3696:17
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4842:19)
at http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4645:62
at forEach (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:357:20)
at createInjector (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:4645:3)
at doBootstrap (http://localhost/pwa-semes/public/js/angular.js:1838:20) Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

I have a button with `ng-click="deleteMessage(message.id)"`

and that fires up this controller:

```
angular.module('messageCtrl', []).controller('messageController', function($scope, $http, Message, $stateParams) {
// object to hold all the data for the new comment form
$scope.messageData = {};

//get id from route
var id = $stateParams.id;
// get all the comments first and bind it to the $scope.comments object
// use the function we created in our service
// GET ALL COMMENTS ==================================================
Message.get(id).then(successCallback);
function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.messages = data.data;
}


// function to handle deleting a comment
// DELETE A COMMENT ====================================================
$scope.deleteMessage = function(id) {

    // use the function we created in our service
    Message.destroy(id).then(successCallbackDestroy);

    function successCallbackDestroy(data){
        Message.get(id).then(successCallback);
    }
};

});
```

and here is the actual service for the api

```
angular.module('messageService', [])

.factory('Message', function($http) {

    return {
        // get all the comments
        get : function(id) {
            return $http.get('api/messages/' + id);
        },

        // destroy a comment
        destroy : function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/pwa-semes/public/api/messages/' + id);
        }
    }

});
```

I have no idea why am I getting this error, or what does it mean. I have basically 1:1 the same file as I have for the actual Threads and those work fine. But deleting a comment inside throws that error and redirects back to homepage instead of just removing the comment in the page. The actual deletion works, it disappears, but with this error. Do you have any idea what to do?

edit: here are my state transitions

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('website', ['ui.router', 'satellizer', 'threadService', 'threadCtrl', 'messageService', 'messageCtrl'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

        // Satellizer configuration that specifies which API
        // route the JWT should be retrieved from
        $authProvider.loginUrl = 'pwa-semes/public/api/authenticate';

        // Redirect to the auth state if any other states
        // are requested other than users
        // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
                controller: 'authController as auth'
            })
            .state('register', {
                url: '/register',
                templateUrl: 'partials/register.html'
            })
            .state('users', {
                url: '/users',
                templateUrl: 'partials/users.html',
                controller: 'userController as user'
            })
            .state('message', {
                url: '/message/{id}',
                templateUrl: 'partials/message.html'
            })
            .state('homepage', {
                url: '/homepage',
                templateUrl: 'partials/homepage.html'
            })
            .state('index', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'partials/homepage.html'
            });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Curious why delete and get has such difference in the paths - ` api/messages/` and `/pwa-semes/public/api/messages/`

Comment: They are the same. The first one is relative, the second one absolute. Probably a leftover from when I was editing it.

Comment: Where is the code that makes the state transition?

Comment: I added the state transtions to the first post

Comment: I'm confused.  You delete a comment using the id then in the callback you get the comment with the same id.  How can you get the comment if you previously deleted it?

Comment: I noticed that after I sent the question here. However, when I put a correct id, it did not change anything. I tried in the input putting delete(message.id, thread.id) and then edited accordingly the delete method. I deleted message with message.id and then get(thread.id), but the result is the same.